# What does the blue highlight around questions mean?

Tags: support

Whenever I'm on a list of questions in Salesforce Stackexchange, some questions are highlighted in blue.  For the life of me I can't deduce what the highlight means.  Any one out there know it's purpose?

[image: Newest Questions List]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those questions have tags that you marked as favorites.